# Prove there is a natural isomorphism between $L(V,L(V,W))$ and $Bil(V \times V,W) $.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

I have to prove the following question, but I'm having trouble. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Let $V$ and $W$ be two (not necessarily finite dimensional) vector spaces. Show there is a natural isomorphism between the vector spaces $L(V,L(V,W))$ and $Bil(V \times V, W)$. Where $L(V,W)$ denotes the set of linear maps between $V$ and $W$ and $Bil(V \times V, W)$ denotes the space of bilinear maps $V \times V \rightarrow W$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword in the problem is "natural", so start by writing down a natural map between the two spaces, which is

$
\phi:\mathrm{Bil}(V\times V,W)\rightarrow L(V,L(V,W))\\
b\mapsto\;(\phi(b):V\rightarrow L(V,W),\; v\mapsto b(v,\cdot)).
$

So $\phi(b)$ is the map that assigns to $v\in V$ the linear map $V\mapsto W, v^\prime\mapsto b(v,v^\prime)$, and as you already remarked, you have to show that $\phi$ is bijective and linear. To make sense of the last statement, you first have to define the vector space structure on $L(V,W)$ and thus on $L(V,L(V,W))$.

Surjectivity of $\phi$: let $F:V\rightarrow L(V,W)$ be a linear map. Then the map $b:V\times V\rightarrow W$ defined through the equation

$b(v_1,v_2):=F(v_1)(v_2)$

is bilinear and by definition $\phi(b)=F$.

Injectivity of $\phi$: $\phi(b)=0$ means that the linear map $b(v,\cdot)$ is the zero-map for every $v\in V$. That is

$\forall v\in V\;\forall v^\prime\in V\quad b(v,v^\prime)=0$,

which means that $b$ is the zero-map.

Comment: I don't really understand the map. Does the bilinear map $b$ get sent to the map that sends a vector $v \in V$ to $b(v, ):V \rightarrow W$?

Comment: Yes. $b(v,\cdot)$ is the linear map ones gets through giving the first variable of $b$ the fixed value $v$. In other words: $b$ is considered as a parametrized family of linear maps, that depend linearly on the parameter.

Comment: So I just have to prove that this map is linear and bijective?

Comment: Also if $\phi :Bil(V \times V, W) \rightarrow L(V,L(V,W))$ is the map you have defined, then $\phi(b)(v)=b(v,\cdot)$, but what is $\phi(b)$?

Comment: I will expand my post.

Comment: Sorry I'm still having trouble with this. $\phi (\lambda a+ \mu b)(v)=(\lambda a+ \mu b)(v,\cdot)= \lambda a(v,\cdot) + \mu b(v,\cdot) = \lambda \phi(a)(v) + \mu \phi(b)(v) $,which proves linearity? But how do you prove injectivity and surjectivity ?

Comment: Ahh , I understand now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by the vector space structure? Do you mean how addition and scalar multiplication is defined?

Comment: Yes. Before you can talk about the linearity of a map, you have to make sure that it maps a vector space to a vector space.